# Select all column but distinct on one column and random

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
ID   Type    Name
1     1      first value
2     1      2nd value
3     2      3rd value
```

I want to select a row with random `Name` for each `Type`. If I use a select with `group by Type`, it returns two rows, always (`first value`, `3rd value`), but I want to make it random: sometimes `first value` and sometimes `2nd value`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your result is "random" in regards to that you cannot rely on always getting the same result. MySQL just gives you some "random" value for name. However, in order to get *some* value they just go through the table and pick what they see first or last, so as long as the table doesn't change, the result won't change either.

Knowing so, simply change the rows' order first:

```
select type, name
from
(
  select type, name
  from mytable
  order by rand()
) randomly
group by type;
```

SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31560/7.